# Como manipular dois conjuntos de dados ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: r

Gostaria de aprender a manipular duas variáveis ao mesmo tempo. Um exemplo, possuo uma base de treinamento e outra de teste para Machine Learning. Como eu poderia aplicar a função *Factor* nas duas ao mesmo tempo(Sendo que o código é idêntico, só muda a base), em vez de aplicar uma a uma? Segue exemplo do código:

```
base_teste$sex<-factor(base_teste$sex, levels = c(' Female', ' Male'), labels = c(0, 1))
base_treinamento$sex<-factor(base_treinamento$sex, levels = c(' Female', ' Male'), labels = c(0, 1))
```

Outro exemplo, utilizar a função `abs()` nas duas ao mesmo tempo, em vez de:

```
base_teste<-abs(base_teste)
base_treinamento<-abs(base_treinamento)
```

Eu tentei utilizar a função primitiva `c()`, porém não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível

> manipular duas variáveis ao mesmo tempo

como diz na pergunta. Mas pode-se manipular uma variável de cada vez de uma forma mais simples.

A melhor maneira é definir funções que transformam de uma forma padronizada. Isso simplifica a chamada das funções.

No primeiro caso, define-se uma função com os valores de `levels` e de `labels` pré-definidos.

```
sex2factor <- function(x, levels = c(' Female', ' Male'), labels = c(0, 1)){
  y <- as.character(x)
  factor(y, levels = levels, labels = labels)
}

base_teste$sex <- sex2factor(base_teste$sex)
base_treinamento$sex <- sex2factor(base_treinamento$sex)
```

No segundo caso, `abs` é uma função interna primitiva genérica e podem ser definidos métodos para ela. A função abaixo é um método para objetos S3 de classe `"data.frame"`.

```
abs.data.frame <- function(x){
  i <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[i] <- lapply(x[i], abs)
  x
}

base_teste <- abs(base_teste)
base_treinamento <- abs(base_treinamento)
```

Comment: Excelente! Eu pensei que existia alguma forma e que era simples. A criação de funções realmente ajuda muito. Poderiam criar um pacote que permitisse essa múltipla manipulação.

Answer (score 2):

Como [respondido pelo @marcus-nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486446/117168), não é possível manipular duas variáveis ao mesmo tempo; a melhor prática em R, se tem algum procedimento que irá repetir várias vezes, é escrever uma função. O que pode fazer, se possui várias bases de dados que seguem o mesmo padrão, é colocar os data.frames em uma lista e usar `lapply` para aplicar funções à todos os elementos da lista:

```
base_lista <- list(teste = base_teste, treino = base_treinamento)

sex2factor <- function(df, var = "sex", levels = c("Female", "Male"), labels = c(0, 1)) {
  df[[var]] <- factor(as.character(df[[var]]), levels, labels)
  df
}

base_lista <- lapply(base_lista, sex2factor)
```

Note que, como será aplicada à uma lista de *data.frames*, a função foi escrita para trabalhar com um data.frame e não uma variável.